# Android Studio - Rendering Error And Can't to Adding Plain TextView

Tags: android, android-studio

When I Create A New Project in Android Studio , Show this  [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86QT8.png)  And i Can't Create EditText And Plain TextView.

Project Structure  [PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCudZ.png)

How I Resolve This Problem ?

My Gradel Build :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mr_enginner.first_project_run"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Have you included the android support library in your gradle file?

Comment: How i Check it ????????

Comment: Open your `build.gradle` file. There should be a line `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'` under `dependencies`.

Comment: i Add Build Gradel

Comment: Did you try building your project again?

Comment: how id do it  ? dude

Comment: In the menu bar, `Build -> Re-build project`.

Comment: Have 2 Error :   1 -- Error:(21, 76) error: cannot find symbol variable fab 2 -- Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure put the java version in the project settings. "Project structure" in File menu.

Comment: Update Question . See that